# Translate foreach to linq to solve running balance

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new in linq and read some stuff on the web about them.

Now, below is a query works fine which is to calculate the project 12-month running balance from the current date. Is it possible to translate this to linq?

It would help me understand the linq better.

```
    var firstDayMonth = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1));
    var months = Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
                           .Select(m => firstDayMonth.AddMonths(m));

    List<SomeDate> SomeDates = new List<SomeDate>()
    {
        new SomeDate { Id = 7, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(0), Balance = 1m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 7, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(0), Balance = 3m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 8, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(1), Balance = 6m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 8, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(1), Balance = 5m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 8, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(1), Balance = 3m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 9, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(2), Balance = 5m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 10, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(3), Balance = 3m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 12, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(5), Balance = 15m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 13, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(6), Balance = 16m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 13, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(6), Balance = 12m },
    };

    var projected12MonthsBalance = new List<SomeDate>();

    foreach(var month in months)
    {
        projected12MonthsBalance.Add(new SomeDate { Month = month, Balance = SomeDates.TakeWhile(s => s.Month <= month).Sum(s => s.Balance) });
    }

    Console.WriteLine(projected12MonthsBalance);

public class SomeDate 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Month { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `TakeWhile` works great if you are sure that the collection is ordered by month, but that `Where` may be better if you aren't sure of the collection order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var projected12MonthsBalance = months.Select(x => new SomeDate 
{ 
    Month = x, 
    Balance = SomeDates.TakeWhile(s => s.Month <= x).Sum(s => s.Balance) 
}).ToList();
```